# Port forwarding with 2 routers

Tags: wireless-router, port-forwarding

I am trying to open port 25565 on my two [routers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LS9yf.png). I want to forward ports from PC 1. I have followed many tutorials but none of them seemed to help me. Router 2 is Asus RT-N12+ and Router 1 is  ZTE ZXHN H267A. I will provide any extra screenshots if needed.

LAN IP of PC 1 is 192.168.1.166, default gateway of router 2 is 192.168.1.1, default gateway of router 1 is 10.0.0.138

Comment: Which device do you want to forward to? What is its IP address? What configuration have you tried so far? Is your 2nd router in bridge mode?

Comment: I am forwarding to pc 1. If you are asking for lan ip, it is 192.168.1.166. It is not, would it help me in some sort of way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> default gateway of router 1 is 10.0.0.138

This indicates that you're behind a CG-NAT. In other words, your router 1 doesn't connect you directly to the Internet - it's connected to another router at your ISP's.

Unfortunately forwarding ports to be accessible from the Internet is not possible with this setup, because you'd have to set up forwarding on the Internet-facing router that your ISP controls.

Consider using VPN software such as Hamachi to work around this restriction.

Comment: Thank you, now I get why every tutorial didn't work with me.