# SSH into raspberry pi on WAN side of router

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi

can anyone help me figure out how to SSH into my raspberry pi in the following situation?  I have an android phone using easytether connected via usb to the pi, then I connected the pi via ethernet to my wireless router's WAN port.  I am unable to figure out how to SSH into the pi on the WAN side of the router from a PC on the LAN side.  Do I need to setup a reverse tunnel or port forwarding?  I cannot get it to work.

[image]

Comment: Hi, you don't seem to have a security question, this will probably get moved

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I played around with SSH reverse tunnel and port forwarding but I don't know what I'm doing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Port forwarding with 2 routers](https://superuser.com/questions/1618696/port-forwarding-with-2-routers)

Comment: Also this: [Port forwarding not working on router using NAT?](https://superuser.com/q/1634528/194694)

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work, I set a static route in my router to the 192.168.2.0/24 network and then restarted the ssh service on the pi

[Asus static route setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETdVM.png)